# React restructure exist component render children (wrap inner)

Tags: reactjs

Imported a list component form third part, such as a example below(render function only):

```
render(){
  return (
    <ul>
      <div>item-1</div>
      <div>item-2</div>
      <div>......</div>
      <div>item-N</div>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

The list component is passed as a prop to my Higher-Order component.

I want add a box component to every item element in HOC.

Expected:

```
<ul>
  <ItemComponent> <div>item-1</div> </ItemComponent>
  <ItemComponent> <div>item-2</div> </ItemComponent>
  <ItemComponent> <div>......</div> </ItemComponent>
  <ItemComponent> <div>item-N</div> </ItemComponent>
</ul>
```

It may use React.Children.map to traverse and add wrap box.

But how to get the whole returned element object like props.children.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are getting the UL element in your children prop so you can't map throw the list items from your HOC